how to calculate the number of valid positions here?
I have an $N \cdot M$ board with some of it's tiles being forbidden meaning they act as a barrier/hole in the board (meaning if you have two rooks and you don't want the rooks to threaten each other one from each side of the forbidden position is a valid placement)
now I have $k$ ($1 \le k \le M \cdot N$) rooks that I want to place in board B with some tiles missing (you can think of the missing tiles as being in set F, such that no rook can attack any other rook. (called non-attacking rook)
I know there must be something with inclusion-exclusion here but I don't know how to do it, I also saw similar problems with generating functions which I didn't learn about at all but this might be a viable solution if it's easier
this for example is some board where the black tiles are the forbidden position and here you want to position 6 rooks

also please correct me if I'm wrong is the generating function of this example is:
$$4032 x^{11} + 37632 x^{10} + 139200 x^9 + 267144 x^8 + 299432 x^7 + 211468 x^6 + 95468 x^5 + 27382 x^4 + 4934 x^3 + 547 x^2 + 35 x + 1$$
and then the coefficient of for example $x^6$ is the number of ways to arrange 6 rooks in that board? (meaning 211468 possible ways of arranging 6 rooks in this specific board)

Can you explain how you found the generating function?

@K.Jiang, I tried following a paper I saw about it, you calculate the generating function of parts of the grid (imagine for example top half and bottom half), and then according to that paper the generating function of the grid is equal to the multiplication of the smaller generating functions, in my case I divided it into 5 generating functions and then found the function by multiplying in wolfram alpha.
I'll say it again, this is literally my first time dealing with those so the possibility of this being right is astronomically low

The generating function (gf) won't be the product of the gf's of subgrids unless those subgrids are independent (i.e., rooks in one subgrid cannot attack rooks in the other).

Also your gf is clearly not correct, because there's no way to place more than $1+2+1+2+1+1=8$ rooks on the grid shown (the number of rooks on any row is bounded by the number of components along that row).

Via enumeration, I obtained $1+35x+455x^2+2832x^3+9107x^4+15276x^5+12886x^6+4988x^7+684x^8$.

The generating function is the "independence polynomial" of a graph with a node for each possible rook and an edge for each pair of attacking rooks.  Search for independence polynomial, and you will find a recursion that considers one node at a time.

Better yet, search for rook polynomial.

You can find the generating function recursively, working one square at a time.  For any grid $G$, consider the leftmost white square in the topmost row.  (Other conventions are possible and give equivalent results; what's important is that the square in question, when removed, doesn't change which remaining pairs of squares attack each other.)  Let $H(G)$ be the grid formed by removing that white square and all the squares it attacks.  Let $K(G)$ be the grid formed by removing just that white square.  Then
$$
f_G(x) = x\cdot f_{H(G)}(x) + f_{K(G)}(x).
$$
The recursion terminates when $G$ is the empty grid, in which case $f_G(x)=1$.

Barring calculation errors... I find the generating function for your grid to be $1+37x+511x^2 + 3573x^3 + 13947x^4 + 30919x^5 + 37314x^6 + 21762x^7 + 4738x^8$.

your example can't be right, for $x$ it got a coefficient of 37 when there are only 35 white squares, to begin with.
i did test it with small examples and it actually worked, can you explain to me how you got this connection? as I really am learning here for the first time about GF I'm still trying to get the hang of it.

Yes, it's not right :).  I need to fix it.  The idea (which works for some grids but not all) is that the number of ways to place $k$ rooks on $G$ is the number of ways to place $k-1$ rooks on $H(G)$ (i.e., you put one on the key square -- say, the upper-left square -- and now can't put any on squares attacked by that square) plus the number of ways to place $k$ rooks on $K(G)$ (i.e., you chose not to put one on the key square).  It doesn't quite work: the targets of the key square may still be needed (even if you can't place a rook on them) to connect other remaining pairs of squares.
